Will type assertions affect the type narrowing of the subsequent code?
I'm encountering a TypeScript issue while trying to create a utility function to register a Vue plugin. Here's a minimal implementation of the code:
import { type Component, type Plugin } from 'vue'
export type ComponentWithInstall<T> = T & Plugin
export type WithInstallPlugin = { _prefix?: string }
export function withInstall<C extends Component, T extends WithInstallPlugin>(
  component: C | C[],
  target?: T
): string {
  const componentWithInstall = (target ?? component) as ComponentWithInstall<T>
  const components = Array.isArray(component) ? component : [component]
  const { name } = components[0]
  if (name) {
    return name
  }
  return ""
}

In the TypeScript Playground, the name property is underlined in red, indicating an error.

const { name } = components[0] show error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Component'.(2339)

However, if I comment out const componentWithInstall = (target ?? component) as ComponentWithInstall<T>, everything works fine. This is perplexing because it seems that the code is not performing type narrowing, and I suspect it might be due to the type assertion. I'm seeking help to understand this issue.

It's weird. Removing const componentWithInstall = (target ?? component) as ComponentWithInstall<T> fixes the issue

@MatthieuRiegler Yes, but this is the code for the minimal implementation and I can't remove it, on another note, uncomment type C = Component['name'] and everything will go back to normal too!

If you opened ms/TS#58050 please write up an answer here saying it's a known bug in TS and update it when more info becomes available.

I realized it was a typescript bug and have opened an issue where the cause of the problem can be viewed.
